# Bounding an expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Prove that if $r \geq 0$ and $E(|X|^r)$ is finite then $E(|X-a|^r)$ is finite for all real numbers $a$.

I have written 
\begin{align*}
E(|X-a|^r) = \int_{|x| \leq |a|} |x-a|^rf_{X}(x) \; dx +
\int_{|x| > a} |x-a|^rf_{X}(x) \; dx
\end{align*}
and am trying to find bounds on the integrals but cannot make any progress.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
 E[|X-a|^{r}] &\leq E[(|X|+|a|)^{r}] \\
              &\leq E[(2\max(|X|,|a|))^{r}] \\
              &\leq 2^{r}E[|X|^{r} + |a|^{r}] \\
              &= 2^{r}(E[|X|^r]+|a|^{r}) < \infty
\end{align*}